# How to make custom toast message to take the whole screen

Tags: android, layout, android-layout, customization, toast

I created layout for my custom toast message, and I set fill_parent to the root element of my custom layout but the size of the layout is still a lot smaller than the whole screen.

Is it possible to set the size of the toast message to take the whole screen ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="center" >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_margin="10dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Note the android:layout_width="fill_parent" and android:layout_height="fill_parent" properties. But still my layout is around one third of the screen . . .

any ideas or suggestions how can I make the toast to take the whole screen ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
toast.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Think you need to set this when calling the toast:

```
Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
myToast.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
```

Can't remember exactly where you would need to put the pipe character to then add Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line `toast.setGravity(Gravity.FILL,0,0)`, it makes the toast fill the whole screen just as you want. It is what I use for custom toasts, which I would like to fill the whole screen.

```
fun showCorectAnswerToast() {
    val inflater = layoutInflater
    val layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
        view?.findViewById<View>(R.id.custom_toast_container) as ViewGroup?)
    val toast = Toast(context)
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.FILL,0,0)
    toast.duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
    toast.view = layout
    toast.show()
}
```